# Wolves for Lambs Trophy

Tags: achievements, assassins-creed-3

What counts as an "additional map" for the [Wolves for Lambs](http://psnprofiles.com/trophy/Assassins-Creed-III/Wolves-for-Lambs) trophy?

> Complete a Wolfpack multiplayer session on any of the additional maps.

Comment: Is this a part of the core game's achievements? If not, it could be for (the inevitable) multiplayer DLC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's part of a map/character multiplayer DLC which is not yet released. If you group your ACIII content by category, it will show these trophies their own section from the non-DLC trophies.

Answer (score -1):

I know that both Virginia and Wolcott don't count, since I've finished the Wolfpack sessions on those with Bear and Night stalker. I haven't seen any that can be unlocked by leveling, prestige, or accolades either. You can see the Wolfpack challenges completed under 'Game progression -> Challenges --> Modes'

Hope for a better answer soon, but this might help out